# How to catch the Failure exception raised during number parsing in ReasonML

Tags: reason, bucklescript

I'm new to Reason. I want to parse a float from a string with proper exception handling.

This works:

```rust
let number = try (float_of_string("1,")) {
  | _ => 0.0;
};
```

But I want to do something like this:

```rust
let number = try (float_of_string("1,")) {
  | Failure(_) => 0.0;
};
```

Unfortunately it doesn't catch the exception. I assume that this is a `Failure` exception because in the developer console I see an error with this data:

```js
[["Failure", -2], "float_of_string"]
```

I also tried raising that error for myself, and it was properly caught:

```rust
try (raise(Failure("test"))) {
  | Failure(_) => Js.log("caught")
};
```

## Edit:

My code should work according to the sandbox: [example on reasonml.github.io/en/try](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=DYUwLgBAdgrgtgIxAJwgXgmZBPCAKAM2AHsBDMAfWIIoGcsBLKAczwCIBGAGjYEpeIAbwBQECAB8IAMVINgMZCDwUBaAHwQADADpNAbmEBfA8IBStbSVaxEKXgaA), thanks @Yawar. It also works if I run it from node instead of browser.

It seems like the exception that is thrown by that function is not from the same source as the exception that we are comparing. Maybe there is a problem with dev environment.

I have created a demo repository - [Exception Demo](https://github.com/jakub-zawislak/reasonml-exception-demo)

Comment: Your exception handler code is working for me: https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=DYUwLgBAdgrgtgIxAJwgXgmZBPCAKAM2AHsBDMAfWIIoGcsBLKAczwCIBGAGjYEpeIAbwBQECAB8IAMVINgMZCDwUBaAHwQADADpNAbmEBfA8IBStbSVaxEKXgaA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a a problem with [moduleserve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moduleserve) that is included in theme `react-hooks` (installed by `bsb -init -theme react-hooks`). In every other method of running code that I tried:

- building a production package using `webpack`
- serving a dev code by `webpack-dev-server`
- using web sandboxes [reasonml/try](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=DYUwLgBAdgrgtgIxAJwgXgmZBPCAKAM2AHsBDMAfWIIoGcsBLKAczwCIBGNgSm4gG8AUBAgAfCADFSDYDGQg8FPmgB8EAAwA6dQG5BAXz2CAUrU0lWsRCm56gA), [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)
- running a `.js` file from command line using `node`

it works fine.

I have created an [issue](https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/issues/4082) at BuckleScript project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked `float_of_string_opt` ? This function has type `string => option(float)` if a error occured it will be `None`

Or you can do

```
switch (float_of_string("1,")) {
| exception (Failure(_)) => 0.0
| x => x
};
```

This is available if the backend OCaml is > 4.02 (BS have upgraded to 4.06 so I think it wil be available for you)

Comment: Thanks for the `float_of_string_opt `. The second one didn't work fork me, I have the same uncaught exception. I have OCaml 4.07.1

Comment: `Belt.Float.fromString` is the same as `float_of_string_opt` . It is from the bucklescript standard library, and has some nice utilities in it.

Comment: @JakubZawiślak it is strange because it work in the playground https://reasonml.github.io/try?rrjsx=true&reason=DYUwLgBAdgrgtgIxAJwgXmvdA+AUBCAZwHcBLMAYwAsIAKAM2AHsBDMAfSfvcLGVKgBzWrDgBKMRADe+CAB8IIAB4UQABzCkmUOgDEWpYDGQha7CTggAGAHRXZCpZaWyAvgG5cuAFKEbzYVEkZFoAIgBGABpQiU9ffyZA+GCw8JixTyA (don't forget to mark as resolved or add new infos)

Comment: I have created a demo that reproduces my issue: https://github.com/jakub-zawislak/reasonml-exception-demo